# package and schedule python folder using azure

Tags: python, azure

I have a python folder that contains the main file and its supporting files.

I run the Main file and it calls the other files.

I now need to package this and schedule it on Azure so it runs every hour.

Can someone guide me on how to do this

Comment: This is my folder structure

[![folder structure][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgzLk.png

Answer (score 0):

A great way to run Python code in Azure without the need for any supporting infrastructure to maintain is Azure Functions--you only pay for the execution of your code. Functions can be triggered using a timer, such as every hour.

To get started, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python